# Is there a better solving algorithm for this Codeforces problem than merely using brute force?

Tags: c++

> You are given an array a1,a2,…,an.
>
> In one operation you can choose two elements ai and aj (i≠j) and decrease each of them by one.
>
> You need to check whether it is possible to make all the elements equal to zero or not.

The following link
https://codeforces.com/contest/1201/problem/B

Comment: What code have you written and where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: What did you try? Please describe your algorithm? How did you fail?

Comment: It's a good idea to put some description of the problem in the title.

Comment: Try iterating over each element and subtracting each Index by one. Then display the array. Then iterate again and if any index value is greater than zero, then no, all the elements in the array are not zero.

Comment: I think it's enough to check if the sum is even and non element has more than the half of the sum: `sum % 2 == 0 && max <= sum / 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's enough to check if the sum is even and no element has more than the half of the sum. Using C++17 with parameter pack expansion and fold expressions it's a short snippet:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
bool check(Ts... an) {
    const auto sum = (an + ...);
    const auto max = std::max({an...});
    return sum % 2 == 0 && max <= sum / 2;
}
```

You have to decrease two elements by one in one step. That means that the sum has to be dividable by two.

One algorithm to get all elements to zero is to decrease the max element and the second max element. For each decrease of the max element you need another element that can be decreased. That works as long as the max element has not more then half of the sum.

Comment: tnx thomas its working but i can not understand your algorithm according to the problem statement they just told me by decreasing one bye bye how did u find this pattern can u please explain what is the clue

Comment: @MdAbulKashim I added a description.

Comment: @MdAbulKashim The easiest way find this pattern is to find algorithms that solve the problem. After some time you'll see a pattern.

Comment: yes sir this more clear to me right now , tnx a lot for your explaination , if u are interested can you connect with me through link id please i think i will benefitted through discussion about such difficult problem please help me i am very trying to master competative programming and spending a lot of time : : here is 
 my linkId :https://www.linkedin.com/in/a-k-m-mirza-bb78a4194/

Comment: @MdAbulKashim You should first learn the programming language before you start competitive programming. In competitive programming you will learn bad code style and bad or even wrong code. You should know how to write good code before you start reading very bad code.

Comment: ,yes sir i am working with cpp for the last couples of year and keep solving different online contest base problem its my humble request to get touch in me to get guide or help from you , how can  i connect with you can u recomend me u are seemed very professional and helpful

Comment: @MdAbulKashim Sorry, but I'm not interested in unpaid personal assistance outside of Stackoverflow. You can ask on Stackoverflow and someone will help you.